# Sendmail Alias for Nonlocal Email Account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail

I admin a server which is running a number of web applications for a software dev team (source control, bug tracking, etc).  The server has sendmail running solely as a transport to the departmental email server over which I have no control.

We have someone who is still in the department but no longer on the dev team so I need to configure the transport agent to redirect all outgoing email (which would be coming from these applications) to the person that has taken their place.  I added an entry in */etc/aliases* like such:

```
olduser@nonlocallhost.com: newuser@nonlocalhost.com
```

But when I run

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail newaliases
```

I get the following error:

```
/etc/mail/aliases: line 32: olduser@nonlocalhost.com... cannot alias non-local names
```

So clearly I'm doing something I shouldn't.  Is there a way to get aliases to work with non-local names or alternatively is their a way to accomplish my goal of redirecting outgoing mail for this user to another one?

Technical Specs if the matter:

- Ubuntu 6.06
- sendmail 8.13 (ubuntu provided package)

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are username only. If you need to specify the domain name as well then you'll need virtusertable instead.

Comment: And here is some info on how to use FEATURE(virtusertable) from the cf/README file http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/