# Can sendmail re-route sending of email?

Tags: email, sendmail, alias

I have a redmine install, that uses sendmail to notify users of issue updates. I have access to the admin account, and also to my regular account. I cannot enter my regular email as the admin account email: each user must have a unique email address.

I would like to alias the admin email so that it is sent to my regular account instead.

So, map  admin@MY_COMPANY.com  ----->   MY_NAME@MY_COMPANY.com

Is this possible.  I am only using sendmail to send mail; the company email server is managed on another server.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems my question was already answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/135872/sendmail-alias-for-nonlocal-email-account

Need to use virtusertable

Answer (score 1):

/etc/aliases is for this.

```
man aliases
```

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I did man aliases, but this file seems to be used for aliasing local users. I guess I need a virtual address that is mapped to my real, external address.

Comment: Um, no.


 The  name  is  the name to alias, and the addr_n are the aliases for that name.  addr_n can be another alias, a local username, a local filename, a com-
       mand, an include file, or an external address.

Comment: *edit*
I thought the admin account existed on that box and needed to send that mail to an external host.  Right.  Aliases won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your company email server supports recipient delimiter (usually '+'), you can just enter, for example:

```
john+whatever001@company.tld
```

Recipient delimiter is supported by Gmail, Google Apps, and Postfix mail servers.

Comment: Thanks, Weboide. I tried this, and sadly (Microsoft Exchange Server) it didn't work.